# Rails 7 - create a controller action called session and you won't be able to access session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a concern that I trigger before every action to track meta information.

```
module MetaRecorder
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def record_meta
    if session && session[:referer].blank?
      session[:referer] = request.referer
    end

    if session && session[:user_agent].blank?
      session[:user_agent] = request.user_agent
    end
  end
end
```

Which I've added to my application controller like so

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include MetaRecorder

  before_action :record_meta
end
```

And I've a controller action called `session` like so

```
class Subscriptions::StripeController < ApplicationController
  def session
  end
end
```

Now my `session` variable in the concern points to this method instead of the session storage like it used to do in Rails 4, 5 and 6.

I've fixed it by skipping the action before this, but just curious about what changes in Rails 7 broke it.

Also curious if my naming is not right; I know the session is a keyword-ish kind of thing in rails, but I suppose naming a controller session should be allowed?

Comment: It is strange that previously it worked

Answer (score 1):

```rb
module MetaRecorder
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def record_meta
    puts method(:session)
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include MetaRecorder
  before_action :record_meta
end

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def session
  end
end
```

Looks broken in every version and points to `session` controller action:

```bash
rails 5.2.8.1 | ruby 2.7.2p137
#<Method: HomeController#session() /myapp/app/controllers/home_controller.rb:5>

rails 6.1.4.1 | ruby 2.7.6p219
#<Method: #<HomeController:0x00000000008cc8>.session() /home/alex/code/SO/rails_six/app/controllers/home_controller.rb:5>

rails 7.0.4.2 | ruby 3.2.1
#<Method: HomeController#session() /home/alex/code/SO/rails_seven/app/controllers/home_controller.rb:5>
```

Are you doing anything in `session` action?

If `session` is actually an empty method and you're just rendering a template then you can remove it.

Also, when `session` method is redefined it does break anything that would need the actual *session* object:

```rb
def session
  puts caller[0]
end
```

```bash
.../actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:490:in `protect_against_forgery?'
.../app/controllers/concerns/meta_recorder.rb:5:in `record_meta'
.../actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
...
.../actionpack-7.0.4.2/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:357:in `form_authenticity_token'
```

Forgery protection calls `session` to set/get the `csrf-token` but it gets your method instead, which is not great.
In the layout `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` uses *session* to render csrf token. I assume you're not doing that, otherwise, it would raise an error.

---

To clarify, `session` is just a [method](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/v2.2.6.3/lib/rack/request.rb#L168), not a keyword.

> ...naming a controller session should be allowed?

It's not exactly forbidden, but you shouldn't redefine existing rails methods. For example, you wouldn't make `def render` action and break all other `render` calls.

---

If `record_meta` method is the only issue you have:

```rb
module MetaRecorder
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    alias_method :rails_session, :session

    def record_meta
      if rails_session[:referer].blank?
        rails_session[:referer] = request.referer
      end
    end
  end
end
```

however, this doesn't fix anything else.

---

You really should just rename the action:

```rb
namespace :subscriptions do
  resources :stripe do
    get :session, action: :get_session, on: :collection
  end
end

def get_session
  # render :session # maybe
end
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I've decided to create a stripe sessions controller and just make it work through that.